# JOIN query yielding unwanted results

Tags: mysql

I'm aware that the Query is performing `how it should` however it is not performing the `way i would like.` The current Query locates all conversations that have messages and presents all messages that are after a provided unix_timestamp.

The issue with this Query is that I need all of the fields from `application_conversation` to be displayed, regardless as to if there is a message available, for example the current query yields the following results:

```
conversation_id | conversation_participant_one | conversation_participant_two | conversation_last_message | conversation_last_message_date | message_id | message_conversation_id | message_sender_id | message_data | message_created_at
       1                      33                             34                      "How are you?"               2016-04-25 08:59:59            1                 1                       33          "How are you?"  2016-04-25 08:59:59
```

The above result is what my current query provides, however there is another row in the `application_conversation` table which matches user `33 and 36`. Below you can see an example of what results I expect to get back from the query. (Basically any fields where the message doesn't exist would be null).

```
conversation_id | conversation_participant_one | conversation_participant_two | conversation_last_message | conversation_last_message_date | message_id | message_conversation_id | message_sender_id | message_data | message_created_at
       1                      33                             34                      "How are you?"               2016-04-25 08:59:59            1                 1                       33          "How are you?"  2016-04-25 08:59:59
       2                      33                             36                           NULL                    1970-01-01 00:00:00           NULL              NULL                    NULL              NULL              NULL
```

Here is the query that I'm currently using:

```
SELECT C.*, M.*
FROM `application_conversation` C
INNER JOIN `application_conversation_messages` M ON M.message_conversation_id = C.conversation_id
WHERE (C.conversation_participant_one = 33 OR C.conversation_participant_two = 33)
AND C.conversation_created_at > FROM_UNIXTIME(0)
AND M.message_created_at > FROM_UNIXTIME(0)
ORDER BY M.message_created_at;
```

Now one of the issues here is that I also have to order the `message_created_at` field of a message, if it does exist, so that I'm not pulling messages older than the timestamp requested by the client. In this query, that means that the message must exist.

How can I go about not requiring the message to exist, but applying the `filter(M.message_created_at > FROM_UNIXTIME(0))` on the message if it does exist, WHILE still returning NULL values if the message does not exist.

I am using MySQL. Bundled with the XAMPP package. Not SQLServer.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`, and put the conditions on the `application_conversation_messages` table in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT C.*, M.*
FROM `application_conversation` C
LEFT JOIN `application_conversation_messages` M ON M.message_conversation_id = C.conversation_id AND M.message_created_at > FROM_UNIXTIME(0)
WHERE 33 IN(C.conversation_participant_one,C.conversation_participant_two)
AND C.conversation_created_at > FROM_UNIXTIME(0)
ORDER BY M.message_created_at;
```

See http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ for an explanation of the difference between `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join instead of an inner join and change the condition from

```
AND M.message_created_at > FROM_UNIXTIME(0)
```

to

```
AND (M.message_created_at > FROM_UNIXTIME(0) OR M.message_created_at IS NULL)
```

Untested but I think it should work and return the result you want.

Comment: Close, but with that condition it will only return C records that have M records after the time, or no M records at all.

Comment: Oh ... my bad. I thought that this was what he wanted, but you're right. I misunderstood the issue.